# Compaing a method with True

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a question about this code.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO MyGuests (firstname, lastname, email)
VALUES ('John', 'Doe', 'john@example.com')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
```

As far as a I know `$conn -> query()`call a method `query` attached to the object `$conn`. How can we compare a method with `===True`?

Comment: If you look at the return-values for [`mysqli->query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php), you'll see that for INSERT queries, it will return a boolean true. Only SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or EXPLAIN queries return a `mysqli_result` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From query command documentation:

> Returns FALSE on failure. For successful SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or
>   EXPLAIN queries mysqli_query() will return a mysqli_result object. For
>   other successful queries mysqli_query() will return TRUE.

In other words it will return `TRUE` if insert was successful and `FALSE` otherwise. So we are comparing function return value after its execution with TRUE to see if it has successfully executed.

You can rewrite this as:

```
$query_sucessfully_executed = $conn->query($sql);

if ($query_sucessfully_executed) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
```

It has the same meaning. I hope this clears things up a bit.

You can learn more about this in [query documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php).